# How to print string involved in Longest common sub sequence using Recursion?

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17, dynamic-programming

I have a code for "Longest Common Sub sequence" but I want not only longest length but also **string involved in it** using recursion.

Any help will be appreciated.

The below code will give only **Longest length**.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int longest_seq( string s1, string s2, int n1, int n2)
{
    if( n1 < 0 || n2 < 0)
      return 0;

    // If last char of both the string matches  
    if( s1[n1] == s2[n2])
      return ( 1 + longest_seq(s1, s2, n1-1, n2-1));

    else
      return max(longest_seq(s1, s2, n1-1, n2),longest_seq(s1, s2, n1, n2-1));
}

int main()
{
    string s1 = "AGGTAB";
    string s2 = "GXTXAYB";

    int n1 = s1.length();
    int n2 = s2.length();

    cout <<longest_seq(s1, s2, n1-1, n2-1);

    return 0;
}
```

current output :

```
4
```

Expected output:

```
4     
GTAB
```

Comment: so what string/char must be involved? you mean longest char sequence which exist in both strings?

Comment: @ Mohammad   yes.  Ans should be GTAB.  currently above code is printing length as 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One crude way of doing thing would be to pass an empty string in the `longest_seq()` function which will populate the string with common sub sequence.

Basically you do it like this -

```
int main()
{
    string s1 = "AGGTAB";
    string s2 = "GXTXAYB";
    string out;

    int n1 = s1.length();
    int n2 = s2.length();

    // Pass out as an input param
    cout <<longest_seq(s1, s2, n1-1, n2-1, out) << endl;
    cout << out << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

You need to change `longest_seq()` too.

```
int longest_seq( string s1, string s2, int n1, int n2, string& out)
{
    if( n1 < 0 || n2 < 0)
      return 0;

    // If last char of both the string matches  
    if( s1[n1] == s2[n2]) {
      out.insert(0, 1, s1[n1]); // Push the matching character in front
      return ( 1 + longest_seq(s1, s2, n1-1, n2-1, out));
    } else {
      string out1, out2; // temporary strings
      int len1 = longest_seq(s1, s2, n1-1, n2, out1);
      int len2 = longest_seq(s1, s2, n1, n2-1, out2);
      out.insert(0, len1>len2 ? out1 : out2); // Add the correct one to the front
      return max(len1, len2);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
4
GTAB
```

You can also change the function to return the string instead of passing the output string as an argument. Then after the function returns you can easily check the length of the output of the function to get longest common subsequence length. You can easily make the necessary changes for that.